# "git branch --track" vs "git checkout --track"

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout

What is the difference between "git branch --track" and "git checkout -b --track", if there  is any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internally `git-branch` is called and then the new branch is checked out. From the [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

> If -b is given, a new branch is
>   created as if [`git-branch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) were
>   called and then checked out; in this
>   case you can use the --track or
>   --no-track options, which will be passed to git branch. As a
>   convenience, --track without -b
>   implies branch creation; see the
>   description of --track below.

Answer (score 6):

If I'm not mistaken, `git checkout ...` will actually create the branch AND switch your working copy to that branch, while `git branch ...` will just create the branch and leave your working copy alone.

Comment: That's the main difference.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for `git checkout`, there should be no difference.

> -b Create a new branch named <new_branch> and start it at <start_point>; see git-branch(1) for details.

Comment: ... apart from the obvious difference that checkout also checks the branch out.